# PHP creating a unique Array with foldernames where no duplicates are mentioned

Tags: php, file

I want to create a unique array to show which folders got deleted. All files are stored in a .txt and can only be read.

```
   function createUniqueArr(array $arr){
      $uniqueArray = array();
      foreach($arr as $i => $string){
        foreach($uniqueArray as $j => $string){
          if(!(str_contains($uniqueArray[$j], $arr[$i]))){
            $uniqueArray[$j] = $arr[$i];
          }
        }
      }
      return $uniqueArray;
    }
```

This is the code i have so far but it does not seem to work.
NOTE: The full Folder name is in the array before all subfiles.
The array that is given looks like this, every new line is a new index:

```
test/test/folder1
test/test/folder1/example.txt
test/test/folder1/example2.txt
test/test/folder1/example3.txt
test/test/folder1/example4.txt
test/test/folder1/example5.txt
test/thisFolderShoudBeShownFully/example6.txt
```

The disered array should be something like this:

```
> test/test/folder1
> test/thisFolderShoudBeShownFully/example6.txt
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: It's unclear how you get from the input to the output. Please describe how you decide to remove something from the input list.

Comment: Dont understand why the desired output contains what it contains? Can you expand on why please

Comment: So I try to out it as this: If a complete folder is in the array (like "folder1") there should only be the folder name in the output. If the file is unique in the array(like the "example.6.txt") the file should be in the output aswell.

Comment: The array is a list of files that got deleted. If a whole folder got delted it should only show the folder name not the specific filenames

Comment: Ah ok so, if a line doesn't end in `.txt` then remove all other lines that start with that string?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate over the list once to get an array of the directories, then again to exclude lines that have a directory in that list. This doesn't require the input to be sorted such that the directory lines are first.

```
$dirs = array_filter($list, fn($line) => !preg_match('/\.txt$/', $line));
$new = array_filter($list, fn($line) => !in_array(dirname($line), $dirs));
print_r($new);

Array
(
    [0] => test/test/folder1
    [6] => test/thisFolderShoudBeShownFully/example6.txt
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But there is one more problem, the array does not only have `.txt`, but various fileextensions